# bash pipe doesn't work in ruby #system and doesn't work in ruby Shell#system

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, perl

I use following code to get opened app icon

```
xprop -notype 32c -id 109051905 _NET_WM_ICON \
                  |    perl -0777 -pe '@_=/\d+/g;
                       printf "P7\nWIDTH %d\nHEIGHT %d\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n", splice@_,0,2;
                       $_=pack "N*", @_;
                       s/(.)(...)/$2$1/gs' \
                  | convert pam:- /tmp/icon.png
```

it work

but when i invoke above bash in ruby, the pipe doesn't work

```
system %Q(xprop -notype 32c -id 109051905 _NET_WM_ICON \
                  |    perl -0777 -pe '@_=/\d+/g;
                       printf "P7\nWIDTH %d\nHEIGHT %d\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n", splice@_,0,2;
                       $_=pack "N*", @_;
                       s/(.)(...)/$2$1/gs' \
                  | convert pam:- /tmp/icon.png)
```

it raise

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads $ ruby /home/roroco/Dropbox/rb/ro_cmds_global/chk/v.rb
convert: negative or zero image size `-' @ error/pnm.c/ReadPNMImage/415.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/icon.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

and I try use Shell#system, it still doesn't work

```
require 'shell'
sh = Shell.new
sh.system(%Q(xprop -notype 32c -id 109051905 _NET_WM_ICON )) | sh.system(%Q(
                   perl -0777 -pe '@_=/\d+/g;
                       printf "P7\nWIDTH %d\nHEIGHT %d\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n", splice@_,0,2;
                       $_=pack "N*", @_;
                       s/(.)(...)/$2$1/gs')) |
    sh.system(%Q(convert pam:- /tmp/icon.png))
```

it raise

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads $ ruby /home/roroco/Dropbox/rb/ro_cmds_global/chk/v2.rb
shell(#<Th:0x000000015de228>): /usr/bin/xprop -notype 32c -id 109051905 _NET_WM_ICON
shell(#<Th:0x000000015de228>): /bin/sh -c 
                   perl -0777 -pe '@_=/d+/g;
                       printf "P7
WIDTH %d
HEIGHT %d
DEPTH 4
MAXVAL 255
TUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA
ENDHDR
", splice@_,0,2;
                       $_=pack "N*", @_;
                       s/(.)(...)/$2$1/gs'
shell(#<Th:0x000000015de228>): /usr/bin/convert pam:- /tmp/icon.png
shell(#<Th:0x000000015de228>): Process finishing, but active shell exists
                               You can use Shell#transact or Shell#check_point for more safe execution.
convert: negative or zero image size `-' @ error/pnm.c/ReadPNMImage/415.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/icon.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

**so how to may it work**

the I find the reason is, use I use ruby #system, the `@_` is empty in perl script, so I think it's perl receive input question, how to fix it?

I can convert perl script to ruby and maybe it work I guess, but I wanna know why perl cannot receive input in ruby #system

Comment: Please provide a trivially simple illustration that perl cannot receive input from Ruby's `system` method. I don't think that is the case. I suggest starting with a very simple case and building up to your complex case gradually, and see where it breaks. Also, I wonder if you may need to shell escape any of this (using Ruby's `shellwords` module).

Comment: Also, I think your \n's will be passed to the shell as single newline characters, and I think you want the literal backslashes and n's. You may need to use %q instead of %Q.

Comment: Also, you can't expect 2 system calls to communicate with each other; each shells out to the OS, runs the command, waits for it to complete. If you need to pipe one's output to the other, you need to specify them in a single call to system.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution,when use too complex bash code, i should use %q() instead of %Q, following code will work:

```
system %q(xprop -notype 32c -id ) + 111149125.to_s + %q( _NET_WM_ICON \
                  |    perl -0777 -pe '@_=/\d+/g;
                       printf "P7\nWIDTH %d\nHEIGHT %d\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n", splice@_,0,2;
                       $_=pack "N*", @_;
                       s/(.)(...)/$2$1/gs' \
                  | convert pam:- jpg:-)
```